# How can I get a list of products related to an invoice in magento?

Tags: magento, backend, invoice

I am trying to alphabetize the items listed on an invoice in the backend of a magento site.

I have access to the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_View_Items object used to display these items in the backend.

Is there any way I can use this object to get a list of product skus and reorder these items?

**Edit:**

Here's the line of code that's gathering the objects for display in the view. I imagine I'd need to get the items sorted before this point –

```
<?php $_items = $this->getInvoice()->getAllItems() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should attach you handler on event "**sales_order_invoice_item_collection_load_before**". Get collection object from event and attach this function

```
$invoiceObject->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'desc')
```

Comment: Thanks. I found an article explaining how to generally hook into events here: http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2010/04/20/writing-a-custom-magento-module/ – But will you help flesh this idea out to a working example?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$this->getInvoice()->getItemsCollection()->addAttributeToSort('sku', 'desc')
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try. Does that modify that actual state of the object? I've added the line in the template that collects the invoice items into the array into my original post – I'll try adding your line right above that one.

Comment: Didn't seem to have any effect, I'll try to poke around some more.

Comment: you will get the collection that needs to be iterated this does not change existing collections

Comment: Ok, that did give me back the same collection of items, but the sort didn't catch